# Child process exit code != 0 when using pipes

Tags: c

```
int cpipe[2];
if(-1==pipe(cpipe)) {
    printf("Pipe failed");
    exit(1);
}

// Fork printenv
childPID=fork();
if(-1==childPID) {
    printf("Fork failed");
    exit(1);
}
else if (0==childPID) {
    // if(-1==dup2(cpipe[1],1)); {
    //  printf("Pipe failed");
    //  exit(1);
    // }
    // close(cpipe[0]);
    // close(cpipe[1]);

    execl("/usr/bin/printenv","printenv",0);

    printf("Execl failed");
    _exit(1);

}
wait(&childExitStatus);
printf("\n%d \n",childExitStatus);
if(childExitStatus!=0) {exit(1);}
```

The above code works; gives childExitStatus = 0, and everyone is happy. Since i want the output of printenv to write to a pipe instead of being printed on screen, i put in the currently commented section. Decommenting that section, however gives the exit code 256, and everyone gets sad. What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line:

`if(-1==dup2(cpipe[1],1)); {`

has a misplaced semicolon.  Change the above line to:

`if(-1==dup2(cpipe[1],1)){`

and you should see the correct return value.

`exit(1)` was always getting called inside the if statement because the if statement was ended with the semicolon and the code inside the braces was always getting executed.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it work by using `dup` instead of `dup2` in the child process. The original code always failed at `dup2` (I changed the exit status for each specific error). But I don't know why.

```
} else if (childPID == 0) {
    close(1);              
    dup(cpipe[1]);         
    ...
}
```

I also added reading from `cpipe[0]` in the parent process, just to test:

```
char c[4096];                          
write(1, c, read(cpipe[0], c, 4096));
close(cpipe[0]);                       
int childExitStatus;                   
wait(&childExitStatus);                
printf("\n%d \n", childExitStatus);    
if (childExitStatus != 0)              
    _exit(5);
```

Comment: Cool, strange that it fails using dup2

Answer (score -1):

Try not write:

```
 close(cpipe[1]);
```

because printenv closes the cpipe[1]. If I am not mistaken.